# why my Django debug tool bar is not showing in the browser?

Tags: django, debugging, django-debug-toolbar

I perfectly followed all the steps in this documentation :

https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

and tried these solutions I found online

adding to the settings module:

```
    
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)


def show_toolbar(request):
    return True


DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG = {
    'SHOW_TOOLBAR_CALLBACK': show_toolbar,
}


if DEBUG:
    import socket  # only if you haven't already imported this
    hostname, _, ips = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
    INTERNAL_IPS = [
        ip[: ip.rfind(".")] + ".1" for ip in ips] + ["127.0.0.1", "10.0.2.2"]
```

but no luck

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the browser. I was using google chrome but when I switched to edge the problem was solved